# adding dynamic widgets are not sized correctly in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.5, kivy-language

I've just started to learn Kivy, and I am having issues with how things gets spaced. I am trying to load images from disk, and then render them in a grid fashion.

However, the images are all squished to the bottom left.

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Gallery>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: wall
            cols: 4
            size_hint_y:  None
            height: self.minimum_height

<Root>:
    gallery: gallery_id

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        ActionBar:
            ActionView:
                ActionPrevious:
                ActionButton:
                    text: "Button"
                    on_release: root.clickme()

        Gallery:
            id: gallery_id
```

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
)
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import glob


class Gallery(Widget):
    def doload(self):

        pngs = glob.glob('/Users/me/Desktop/*.png')[:150]

        for p in pngs:
            bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            label = Label(text='MyLabel')
            image = AsyncImage(source=p, size_hint=(1, None), keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True)

            bl.add_widget(image)
            bl.add_widget(label)

            self.ids.wall.add_widget(bl)

class Root(Widget):
    gallery = ObjectProperty(None)

    def clickme(self):
        print("i've been clicked")

    def update(self):
        self.gallery.doload()

    pass



class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = Root()
        root.update()

        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.size = (800, 600)
    MyApp().run()
```

This is what it looks like (you can see the images are squished, bottom left):
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYZOT.png)

How can I space these images correctly? Something like this: [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iST85.png)

As a bonus, is there a way to dynamically determine the `cols` property in the `GridLayout` when the user resizes the window? For example if the user increases the width of the window, then the app should support a larger `col` size. Similarly, if the user shrinks the window, the app should decrease the `col` size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Gallery>:
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            id: wall
            cols: 4
            size_hint_y:  None
            height: self.minimum_height
```

Gallery is a subclass of Widget, therefore it makes no special effort to size or position its children, therefore the ScrollView has the default size of (100, 100) and pos of (0, 0), therefore the GridLayout is placed within the same region, therefore all your images are put in that small area.

The solution is to make Gallery an appropriate layout type, e.g. a BoxLayout.

> As a bonus, is there a way to dynamically determine the cols property in the GridLayout when the user resizes the window?

In kv: `cols: some_function_of(Window.size)`.

Comment: I think I get it... I tried it out and changed the class definition: `class Gallery(BoxLayout)`, but now I don't see any of my images and I only see 4 of my labels. There should be 150 images+labels?

Comment: Are they simply outside the visible part of the ScrollView? What happens if you try scrolling?

Comment: I can't scroll at all. You can see here that I only see 4 labels and empty images: https://imgur.com/a/xBOOK7R

Comment: ah i figured it out... the `size_hint_y:  None` was reducing the width to 0, I think. Removing that and I see the images. Although they are all squashed together and no scroll happens either, just all kinda stacked vertically on top of each other like solitare. Is it because my dynamic `BoxLayout` ("`bl`") doesn't have a size when I add it to the grid? I tried playing with the size attribute but the images are still stacked anyhow. Still dont' quite understand how things get laid out in kivy :(